# TextView with Close Button in Android

Tags: android, textview

Can I add a textview with close button over it.

Lets say i have given an option to user to remove some of the texts from the screens.

EG:

WASIF[x] Azhar[x] Kirmani[x] is there any UI Component which i can use for this functionalit

Answer (score 1):

You could use a relative layout and put the Button over the text view like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <EditText android:id="@+id/greatTextView" android:text="Sample text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
    <Button android:id="@+id/superButton" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="X" 
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution you can do is whenever the user hits the 'x' button you can just do this:

```
myEditBox.setText("");
```

Or is your question how to construct the the editbox with the 'x' button over it?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <EditText android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/editText1">
        <requestFocus></requestFocus>
    </EditText>
    <Button android:id="@+id/button1" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:text="x" android:textSize="20dp"></Button>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: how to construct the the editbox with the 'x' button over it?

Comment: I've editted my response of how to do a simple version of the edit box with an x over it on the right.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an OnclickLister on the TextView that display either the WASIF[x] or [x].

Little example:
main.xml:

```
<TextView 
   android:id="@+id/myClickableTextView"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"               
   android:text="WASIF[x]"
   android:onClick="onClick"                
   android:clickable="true"/>
```

MyActivity.java:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

      public void onClick(View v) {
        ...
      }  
   }
```

It is important to make the view clickable with this xml-attribute android:clickable="true" otherwise the clickhandler isn't called.